# Make writePropertyValueInPropertyFile() return 'void'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11

I am trying to import a method from one package to another but am unable to do so.
So I have a method of `Properties`, where I have to write information on certain sections and retrieve them.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import static co.spotify.utilities.Log.error;

public class PropertiesUtils {
    public static void writePropertyValueInPropertyFile(String fileName, String propertyName, String propertyValue)
            throws IOException {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(in);
        in.close();
        props.setProperty(propertyName, propertyValue);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        props.store(out, null);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I have another package with name of `utils`, now here, I am unable to import that `writePropertyValueInPropertyFile` method.
I am using following approach:

```
import static co.spotify.utilities.PropertiesUtils.writePropertyValueInPropertyFile;

public class UserInformationConstants {
       writePropertyValueInPropertyFile(userPropertiesFileName, "registeredEmail", userRegisteredEmail);
}
```

and IntelliJ is indicating that `Make writePropertyValueInPropertyFile() return 'void'`

What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write code directly into the body of a class. It has to be within a method.

Try something like the following instead:

```java
import static co.spotify.utilities.PropertiesUtils.writePropertyValueInPropertyFile;

public class UserInformationConstants {
    public static void yourMethodNameHere() {
        writePropertyValueInPropertyFile(userPropertiesFileName, "registeredEmail", userRegisteredEmail);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, Upon calling that function, it is asking me to make `yourMethodNameHere` void.